# How to exactly specify the id of td? jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have many tds ,each td has id.When id is variables,it failed.When id is confirm(like A12),content will display.Then I tried '#A'+i+j,but the result always #A921.The code is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
for(var i=1;i<9;i++)
for(var j=1;j<21;j++)
{  
 $('#A'+i+j).click(function (){
 alert('#A'+i+j);
 $('#content').css('display','block'); 
 $('#selectID').val('#A'+i+j);
  });
}   
});
</script>
```

Who can help me? A+i+j should be A11 A12........A820.My PHP code:

```
<?php 
function output($a,$b,$color)
{
 if($b)
 {
  echo '<td style="background-color:'.$color.'" id="'.$a.'">'.$b.'</td>';
 }
 else
 {
  echo '<td>'."N".'</td>';
 }
}

function cabinetcolor($a)
{
    if($a=="G")
    {
            $color=green;
    }
    else if($a=="GR")
    {
            $color=gray;
    }
    else if($a=="P")
    {
            $color=purple;
    }
    return $color;
}

 while($k<9)
 {  
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td width="50px" cellpadding="10px">A'.$k.'</td>';
    for($j=1;$j<21;$j++)
    {
      $sql = "select * from hpc where cabinetNum='A".$k."".$j."'";
      $res = $conn->query($sql);
      $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 
      $color=cabinetcolor($row[45]);
      output($row[1],$row[2],$color);
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: share some HTML would be better

Comment: @Mark,html code have been added

Comment: the issue has to do with how `i` and `j` are scoped inside callbacks. notice how they always have their last value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of courseit will be #A921, because base on your code when you click on any td, your i , j variables already reached to 9 and 21, basically you cannot use for loop for this problem.

Instead you can create a function like this :

```
function doSomething(el){
  alert(el.id);
  $('#content').css('display','block'); 
  $('#selectID').val(el.id);
}
```

and in your HTML, call this function in your td tag like this :

```
echo '<td onclick="doSomething(this)" style="background-color:'.$color.'" id="'.$a.'">'.$b.'</td>'
```